# RegEx to perform multiple replacements

Tags: regex, powershell, timestamp

I have been playing with a regular expression and it has become a bit more complex.  I am running Powershell 3.0 and have the following timestamp:

> 2017-07-26T00:00:39Z

I use the following code to strip the seconds from the timestamp and replace them with 00:

```
$($_.Timestamp -replace '^(.*)(\d\d)(.*)$','${1}00$3')
```

Now my use case became more complex because the timestamps are now going to be ingested in the format:

> 2017-08-17 00:00:34

This complicates things because I need the format to be adjusted in order for KML to utilize it properly as a placemark timestamp.  So I still need the seconds stripped out and replaced with 00 but also need a T to replace the space in between the date and time and a Z appended to the end to represent Zulu for the timestamp.  Is something like this possible in a single regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think regular expressions are necessary. You should be able to use the `DateTime` object; e.g.:

```
$date = Get-Date "2017-07-26T00:00:39Z"
```

You can use the object's `ToString` method to output in the string format you want; e.g.:

```
$date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Regex provides more flexibility when dealing with "unclean" input. Thus, regex might be necessary here, pay attention at the `.*` part in OP regex that implies there might be some rubbish text after the timestamp.

Comment: Still working with datetime objects, with most versions (v3+ I think) of PowerShell you can just cast his input as a `[datetime]` object and just output it as desired `([datetime]'2017-08-17 16:27:34').ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:00Z')` comes out as `2017-08-17T16:27:00Z`. Or have `Get-Date` output the desired string immediately with `get-date '2017-08-17 16:27:34' -f 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:00Z'`, which produces the same output.